# c++ large file performance with char* and pitfalls

Tags: c++, string, text, memory-management, char

I'm currently writing and manipulating MASSIVE text files (180+Mb).
And I'm trying to come up with a memory schema to handle this data.

bigfile.txt is a \r delimited list of strings.

My current idea is to preform:

```
std::string str;
std::ifstream in2("bigfile.txt", std::ios::binary);
if (in2.is_open())
{
    in2.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    str.reserve(in2.tellg());
    in2.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    str.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in2)),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}

for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size();i++)
{
    if (str[i] == '\r')
    {
        str[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Then I go through the list and map a vector of char* to the string.

Is there any downfalls of this design?

And as long as I don't delete the char*'s I shouldn't leak any memory right? cause the string will loose scope and clear it correct?

Comment: If you are going to manipulate them eventually, why you don't just read and manipulate at the same time instead of storing them in a vector?

Comment: Why not read it line by line into a `vector` of `string`s?  That way you don't need to worry about `char*`s

Comment: @CroCo has the right idea--do as much processing as you can while reading the file.  Since your program will be somewhat busy with disk reads, any computation you can interleave with I/O will be basically free.  To answer your other question: no, your code does not leak memory now.

Comment: @user3553031 Try to read a 180mb text file with your method, then mine.

Comment: @StevenVenham: My method took me approximately 13 seconds to generate a vector of strings, whereas your method took me approximately 11 seconds to generate a vector of pointers.  Mine also took 7 lines of code rather than 18.  Unless you're running this code a *lot*, I'd still use my method for its convenience.

Comment: `stringstream fileStream; fileStream << in2.rdbuf(); string fileStr =fileStream.str();
`

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal Whats the benifits of using a stringstream over this?

Comment: Ok well. 
avarage time ss with prealoc:2126ms
avarage time ss without:2103ms 
avarage time ifstream:3044ms